# How remove face?

Tags: edit-mode, units

How can i remove that face on angle ?
[image]

Comment: Please add more context to your question. I don't know what face you are taking about, or what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @Relevred I want to eliminate those overlapping parts.
They are two rods that I have joined to form a 90 degree angle, but obviously those protuberances come out on the corner that I would like to eliminate.

Comment: @borja Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you tell us only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, with the [edit] button under the post, don't post it in the comments. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can just grab each vertex of the bad poles individually, press ctrl+V (in edit mode) and click the *slide* option. Then, move them up the pole so that they go into the mesh and are out of view.